# Get selected index in Kendo UI ComboBox with the TypeScript

Tags: combobox, kendo-ui, typescript

I'm missing the possibility to get selected index in the Kendo UI ComboBox with the TypeScript and latest typing definition kendo.all.d.ts (UI for ASP.NET MVC Q1 2014)

```
var comboBox = $(this).data("kendoComboBox");
if (comboBox) {
    if (comboBox instanceof kendo.ui.ComboBox) {

        var kendoUiComboBox: kendo.ui.ComboBox = <kendo.ui.ComboBox>comboBox;
        kendoUiComboBox.?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fundamental problem with TypeScript is that no one maintains these .d.ts definition files. And as you are seeing, even when a company does try to maintain them, sometimes the developers miss things since they have to be maintained by hand. Last time I looked for a jQuery .d.ts file, I found 3 of them in minutes that were all different.

TypeScript gripes aside, you can bypass the compilation and intellisense check by just casting to `<any>`.

```
var selected = (<any>kendoUiComboBox).select();
```

Comment: Yes i think also that the definition files are less maintained. But thank for your tip, it is great to know!

Answer (score 1):

Going through the documentation : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox `select` is a getter/setter function.

You should be able to do

```
var comboBox = $(this).data("kendoComboBox");
if (comboBox) {
    if (comboBox instanceof kendo.ui.ComboBox) {

        var kendoUiComboBox: kendo.ui.ComboBox = <kendo.ui.ComboBox>comboBox;
        var selected = kendoUiComboBox.select();
    }
}
```

Comment: The select method is awaiting parameter in TypeScript. See the definition file. You can use this method in pure JavaScript but not in TypeScript

Comment: @AntonKalcik then their definition is incorrect. They need to use the getter/setter pattern https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/2001#issuecomment-39838373